# Reverse button animation

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4

I'm new to swift, and learning button animations. I was able to figure out how to get the button to slide in from the bottom, but I'd like to have it slide out from where it was placed after a it's clicked, before the segue to the next view controller scene. Any help or pointing in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

```
@IBOutlet var button: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    button.center.y = self.view.frame.width + 300

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.2, delay: 0.2,
                   usingSpringWithDamping: 3.0,
                   initialSpringVelocity: 4.0,
                   options: [], animations: ({
                   self.button.center.y = self.view.frame.width / 0.82
                   }), completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create an `@IBAction` and link your button with it (select type of action UIButton). Unbind segue from button.
2. Move you code to this action, address sender instead of `button` to use button that was touched instead of fixed one.
3. In completion handler instead of nil supply

Completion block:

```
{_ in
     self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "<seugueId>", sender: self)
 }
```